# LGPL or similar GUI toolkit for Python3 and above

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've been using Python 3 for some months and I would like to create some GUIs. Does anyone know a good GUI Python GUI framework I could use for this?

I don't want to use [TkInter](http://wiki.python.org/moin/TkInter) because I don't think it's very good.  I also don't want to use [PyQt](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PyQt) due to its licensing requirements in a commercial application.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_widget_toolkits#Comparison  Look for Python bindings

Comment: Why can't you create commercial applications with QT?

Comment: If there would be "THE cool GUI", nobody would bother with the ugly ones. The choice needs to fit the prerequisites. I hardly doubt, that license issues would be of your concern. You probably should look into somethin, which is easy to learn for beginners, and tkinter might just fit the bill in your case.

Comment: @idiot, you are new to SO. It is good to accept one answer if it satisfies your question. Otherwise, please update your question and/or comment on the replies for asking more.

Comment: @idiot I've reworded, renamed, and retagged your question so it fits with the spirit of the SO community.  I would seriously suggest you read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) before asking any more questions as it contains very good information on how to ask questions properly; which will make it more likely you will receive an answer. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, I suggest you to stay with Python 2.x if you want to develop commercial products **at this moment**.

This is because it is still the most widely available version of Python.
Currently, Ubuntu ships with 2.7.2 and OS X Lion with 2.7.2, too.

Regarding PyQT, you can use Nokia's re-implementation of it, [PySide](http://pyside.org). It is under LGPL, so yes, you can create commercial products. Moreover, QT also transitioned to LGPL. See [QT License](http://qt.nokia.com/products/licensing) here.

Update: Additionally, support for Python 3.x is still under development for many GUI frameworks, PySide included.

Comment: I don't see why someone should stay with python2.x without a proper reason. This way the application would be tied to a complete recoding in the future. . . The only reason to stay in 2.x should be non compatibility with plugins that are not yet available in 3.x.

Comment: @jlengrand: If the code is decent, porting it can often be a matter of fixing a few corners doing stuff that's discouraged anyway and was disallowed in 3.0 (e.g. mixing text with binary data, or old-style classes), and then running 2to3 over it. If the code is written with porting in mind, it can be even easier. And there *is* a good reason here: Most GUI toolkits don't support 3.x yet (or only experimentally).

Comment: @jlengrand Moreover, idiot (lol) wants to code commercial applications. Compatibility and ease of installation + support on what is already existent is a plus for Python 2.x.

Comment: I agree with both of you. Nevertheless, Python 2.x is meant to die. Choosing 2.x now for a long term project would still be a weird choice in my mind. That said, 3.x is often not the first thing that come in developers mind. . .

Answer (score 1):

Hummm. . . .
Hard to believe that Qt is forbidden for commercial use, as it has been created by some of the most important companies in the world . . . http://qt.nokia.com/

Go for pyQt ;)

Comment: Qt has several licences, for a long time one has to pay to get it licensed in a way that allows closed source. Licensing changes a while ago added an LGPL option, so it *may* be possible (but honestly I never had to check). But PyQt didn't do that switch: ["Unlike Qt, PyQt v4 is not available under the LGPL."](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/pyqt/intro).

Comment: @delnan you are right, that is the reason why Nokia re-implemented their Python bindings under the name PySide. And yes, LGPL permits commercial use.

Answer (score 1):

You probably mean that **PyQt** can only be used for GPL projects. However, the equivalent [PySide](http://www.pyside.org) Python bindings for QT are LGPL, like QT itself, so you *can* use those; unfortunately, they only support Python 2.5/7 at the moment.

If you don't mind being cross-platform, you can fall back on the win32api stuff (bleh), or go the hybrid way with [Jython](http://www.jython.org) (which supports Swing as well as any other Java-based toolkit) or IronPython (which uses .Net).

Answer (score 0):

Pyside might be the best bet for you :
http://www.pyside.org/

It is basically Qt but under the LGPL license, which means you can use it in your commercial application.

Comment: I was going to nag that it hasn't been ported to 3.x yet. I checked, and it turns out experimental support started a few releases ago. Very cool.

Answer (score 0):

Well, If you feel Qts is not suitable(thats hard to belive either) you could switch to

WxPython . It too has an good learning curve and can satisfy your commersial needs

Comment: i guess wxPython is for python 2.x But i asked for python 3.x